# Intellij cannot find android device

Tags: android, intellij

I'm going to write android apps using intellij-ultimate. 
When I want to run the code I have to choose a device I can create a virtual device or use a connected device to run my code.
I've connected a Samsung s4mini but intellij doesn't recognize it. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Android studio has it's installation instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html)

This process can be done by downloading the [tar.gz](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.3.0/android-studio-ide-145.3537739-linux.zip) file.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.2.3.0/android-studio-ide-145.3537739-linux.zip
```

Unpack this ZIP file as regular user and move the uncompressed folder into */usr/local* you'll need super privilñeges for that.

Then install this dependecies

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

In the Android studio folder you can CD into the *bin* folder and execute

Simply run

```
/usr/local/android-studio/binstudio.sh
```

And follow the instructions in the GUI, I use a separate HDD for the HOME folder so kept the installation of the SDK there as suggested by the Installer *wizard*.

Comment: Please include the important parts of that link in case the link breaks or changes or is removed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster How do you like that ? TY btw